# Condicional dentro de series de HighCharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

¿Cómo hago para condicionar el número de series que deseo que se me desplieguen en mi gráfica de *Highcharts*?

Es decir:

- Si el valor `a` **es igual a 1** que muestre lo siguiente:

[image: g1]

```js
series: [{
  name: '<span style="font-size: 65%">' + datos.fecha[0] + '</span>',
  color: '#ff6600',
  data: [datos[0][0], datos[0][1], datos[0][2], datos[0][3], datos[0][4]],
  pointPlacement: 'off'
}]
```

- Si el valor `a` **es igual a 2** entonces:

[image: g2]

```js
series: [{
  name: '<span style="font-size: 65%">' + datos.fecha[0] + '</span>',
  color: '#ff6600',
  data: [datos[0][0], datos[0][1], datos[0][2], datos[0][3], datos[0][4]],
  pointPlacement: 'off'
},{
  name: '<span style="font-size: 65%">' + datos.fecha[1] + '</span>',
  color: '#0f6600',
  data: [datos[1][0], datos[1][1], datos[1][2], datos[1][3], datos[1][4]],
  pointPlacement: 'off'
}]
```

Comment: Con el código que compartes, no se termina de comprender el problema: Dices que dependiendo del valor de `a` se debe mostrar una cosa u otra, pero en el código que compartes no hay ninguna referencia a ningún `a`. Deberías crear un [mcve] para mostrar mejor el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí: Deseas que se pueda elegir que numero de series mostrar en el renderizado de la gráfica.

1. Guarda tus series una variable antes de renderizar tu gráfica.

```js
    var $series =  [{
      name: '<span style="font-size: 65%">' + datos.fecha[0] + '</span>',
      color: '#ff6600',
      data: [datos[0][0], datos[0][1], datos[0][2], datos[0][3], datos[0][4]],
      pointPlacement: 'off'
    },{
      name: '<span style="font-size: 65%">' + datos.fecha[1] + '</span>',
      color: '#0f6600',
      data: [datos[1][0], datos[1][1], datos[1][2], datos[1][3], datos[1][4]],
      pointPlacement: 'off'
    }];
```

2. Usa slice para mostrar solo el numero de series que deseas:

```js
    var $series = [{..}, {..}]// muchos elementos
    
    // aqui codigo del renderizado
    series: $series.splice(0,2); // El 0 corresponde al elemento inicial, el 1 sería el elemento final (Recuerda que los arreglos(array) comienzan con 0.
```